# How to understand the opcode mips pseudo instruction move?

Tags: mips, mips32

found an explanation of the pseudo instruction

```
Move (move)

The move pseudo instruction moves the contents of one register into another register.

move $1, $2
translates to

add $1, $2, $0
```

Here is the code.

```
25f0a003       move fp, sp
```

but add opcode is like this.

```
31-26 special   0x000000
25-21 rs       it should be  0x1d
20-16 rt       it should be  0x0
15-11 rd       it should be  0x1e
10-6  0        it should be  0x0
5-0   add      it should be  0x32
```

but the opcode is different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got the explanation you quoted in your question, but it's up to the assembler to decide how to implement pseudo-instructions.

The word 25f0a003 doesn't make sense as a MIPS instruction, but if we swap the bytes around to 03a0f025 then we get:

```
0000 0011 1010 0000 1111 0000 0010 0101

=>

000000 11101 00000 11110 00000 100101

=>

or $30, $29, $0

=>

or $fp, $sp, $zero
```

So in this case, the assembler you used translated `move $fp, $sp` into `or $fp, $sp, $zero`.